# Does the electric field of a cylinder limit the one of a finite 1D wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields

I have computed the electric field for a finite cylinder of charge $Q$, length $L$ and radius $R$ with a uniform distribution of charge over all of its volume to be
$$\vec{E}(x) = 2K_E\frac{Q}{R^2L}\left(|x|-|x-L|+\sqrt{R^2+(x-L)^2}-\sqrt{R^2+x^2}\right)\vec{i},$$
along its longitudinal axis.

Likewise, I have computed the one for a finite 1D wire with charge $Q$ and length $L$ to be
$$\vec{E}(x)=K_E\frac{Q}{L}\left(\frac{1}{|x-L|}-\frac{1}{|x|}\right).$$

I thought that the limit of the former as $R\to0$ should yield the latter, but that limit clearly diverges to infinity. However, I can't find any mistake in the computation of neither.

Would anyone here be able to give me any hints on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: A usual wire is electrically neutral, not least because of this. What actually are you asking?

Comment: Hey @naturallyInconsistent, I was asking not for a conducting wire, but for a 1D uniform charge distribution (think of a charged thin rod).

Comment: I know that; but I mistook that you were asking for a physical impossibility, as opposed to a computational mistake. I'm sorry. I know what you are trying to ask now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result for the thick cylinder doesn't actually diverge as $R \to 0$.  Note that in the expression
$$
\frac{1}{R^2} \left(L+\sqrt{R^2+(x-L)^2}-\sqrt{R^2+x^2}\right)
$$
the quantity in parentheses approaches $L + |x - L| - |x| = 0$ as $R \to 0$ (assuming that $x > L$ and $x > 0$.)  So in this limit we have an expression of the form $\frac00$ and we can't necessarily say that it's divergent.

To find the limit correctly, you should first rewrite the quantity in brackets as
$$
L+(x- L)\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{(x - L)^2} + 1} - x \sqrt{\frac{R^2}{x^2}+1}
$$
(again assuming that $x > L$ and $x > 0$.)  Then use the binomial expansion to simplify the square roots assuming that $R \ll x- L$ and $R \ll x$.  If you do this, several terms will cancel and you'll find that the result remains finite when divided by $R^2$;  moreover, it will give you back your result for the thin wire.

Comment: Thank you very much!